# Correct logging for exception in coroutine Python3 + Tornado4.3 + native logging module

Tags: python, logging, format, tornado

In Tornado, an Exception is encapsulated within a Future and the caller to an async function must yield the Future to unpack the Exception. How do I get the log message to correctly print out the function name and line where the exception happens if I have a long calling chain of async functions ?

For example, in the code below:

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s : %(lineno)s'\
         ' - %(funcName)20s() - %(message)s\n'

logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)

...

@gen.coroutine
def layer_2():
    return(yield async_func())

@gen.coroutine 
def layer_1():
    return(yield layer_2())

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    try:
        yield layer_1()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning('Error: {}'.format(str(e))
```

If there is an Exception raised in `async_func()`, the log message `lineno` and `funcName` are those of `main()`, not of `async_func()`.

Is there any solution short of `try` and `catch` every `yield` statement ? Thanks!

Edit 1: I realized the answer to my question might have nothing to do with Tornado, but I'm just including it here because it's my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using Python 3, and in Python 3, exceptions from Futures have a traceback available automatically. Use `logging.exception` to print it:

```
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    try:
        yield layer_1()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

There's nothing mysterious going on in `logging`. You can print the traceback yourself:

```
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    try:
        yield layer_1()
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Compared to a traceback from a regular function call stack, this traceback has some extra stuff in it: calls to gen.Runner.run, part of Tornado's coroutine implementation. But it serves its purpose: you can see that `main` is at the top of the stack and `async_func` is at the bottom.

This works in Python 3 because every Exception has a Traceback attached to it, and Tornado correctly attaches a coroutine's traceback to the exception as it unwinds the stack during exception handling. [For some history, see the docs on Future](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future).

And finally, if you replace `gen.coroutine` with `async def` you'll get nice clean tracebacks implemented by the Python 3.5 interpreter itself.

Comment: Ah this is super helpful! Thank you! I think this is the second question that you have helped me with!